# How to Parse a DateTime String to Support 24 hours timing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, formatting

I'm trying to use DateTime.TryParseExact as below:

```
DateTime modifiedSinceDateTime;

var succeeded = DateTime.TryParseExact(modifiedSince, "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None,
    out modifiedSinceDateTime);
```

but it fails with this DateTime value: `2013-06-06T22:41:20` which suggests my date time pattern is not right. I think the pattern doesn't support 24 hours timing format, only up to 12 hours

What should be the correct date pattern like?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple enough - change the `hh` to `HH`.

[`hh`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#hhSpecifier) is for 12 hour clocks, [`HH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#HH_Specifier) for 24 hours, as can be seen in the documentation for [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).